# Match route only if query param exists

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I want to match this route if url is `/test?x=5` and don't match if param x is not provided (`/test`):

```
stateProvider.state({
    name: 'someState',
    url: '/test?x',
    template: '<div>matched</div>'
});
```

This configuration does not work, route is matched in both cases. I need required **query** param.

I was expecting clean solution like this:

```
stateProvider.state({
    name: 'someState',
    url: '/test',
    params: {
        x: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    template: '<div>matched</div>'
});
```

Comment: Can you change URL to `url: '/test/:x'`? It will make unique pattern, and you can achieve what you needed..

Comment: @PankajParkar no, I can't, that's the problem

Comment: Change urls to '/test/:x' or check if the param exists in the receiving controller. If not exists x then redirect to another route or raise an error.

Answer (score 4):

You could write resolve on the current route and from that `resolve` function whether the parameter is exists or not

```
stateProvider.state({
    name: 'someState',
    url: '/test?x',
    template: '<div>matched</div>',
    resolve: {
      xExists: ['$stateParams', '$state', 
         function($stateParams, $state){
            if(!$stateParams.x) $state.go('someotherstate');
         }
      ]
    }
});
```

---

Other better solution would be changing the route pattern to `/test/:x` which will make your pattern unique. If it doesn't match the route pattern, ui-router will take care of navigating to default route(if you have configured it with `$urlRouter.otherwise`).

```
url: '/test/:x',
```